# Drools 5.0 - Locally... Global

Tags: drools

I'd like to declare a global variable that is scoped to only my rules file.
For example: variable $reUseMe is only declared once.

rule 1

$reUseMe : POJO(val = 1)
  //other conditions

rule 2

$reUseMe > val

Comment: I'll just insert it into the working memory. Was trying not to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no scoped global variables, but in some cases rule inheritance helps.

```
rule "Rule 1"
  when
    $reUseMe :POJO( val == 1 )
  then
end

rule "Rule 2" extends "Rule 1"
  when
    # You can use the variables from Rule 1
    POJO( val > $reUseMe.val ) 
  then
end
```

Only LHS is added. RHS from Rule 1 is ignored in Rule 2.

Comment: This is helpful. 
Could you share a link to  any documentation on this?
Thanks!

Comment: I could only find this blog entry, check "category rules" http://blog.athico.com/2008/10/while-everyone-was-having-fun-at-orf.html
That is how it is used in Guvnor, but in DRL you use it like in my example, what it does is it copies the condition of Rule 1 on top of Rule 2. This way you can use all the variables and conditions you had in Rule 1 in Rule 2.

Answer (score 3):

you can refer to globals in LHS via eval:

global SomeType variable

rule ...
   when 
     ...
     eval(variable > something)